# How to give name for custom directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

> Now i'm using camelcase directive name, like below

```
<code-input:text></code-input:text> (or)
<code-input-text></code-text-input>
```

**can i use custom directice name and attribute like this,**

```
<code-input:text dirType="text" labelHead="Code" dirName="Code" dirId="code" dirClass="form-control" dirModel="taskCreateForm.code" section-class="col col-3 required"></code-input:text>
```

if i give like this means , then doesn't render template from directive.because of, i have set every attribute for this is dynamically.

```
scope : {
            dirName : '@',
            dirType : '@',
            dirModel : '=',
            labelHead : '@',
            sectionClass : '@',
        },
template : [
                   '<section class="{{sectionClass}}">',
                   '<label class="label">{{labelHead}}</label>',
                   '<label class="input">',
                   '<input type="{{dirType}}" name="{{dirName}}" id="{{dirId}}" class="{{dirClass}}" ng-model="dirModel">',
                   '</label>',
                   '</section>'
                   ].join(''),
```

can anyone give me guidance..is't possible or any issue has occurred because of this.else it's not standard way?

Comment: another one question..what about custom directive attribute names..shall i give attribute name like dirName instead of dir-name in custom directive tag.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization:

> The **normalization** process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to `camelCase`.

That is to say, `code-input-text` and `codeInputText` are equivalent and match the `codeInputText` directive.

Comment: what about custom directive attribute names..shall i give attribute name like dirName instead of dir-name in custom directive tag.?

Comment: @udays The directive name should be in `camelCase`, but the element/attribute name can be in the case you want, as long as it is normalized to the directive name. Angular recommends using a dash-delimited format though, i.e. `code-input-text`.

Comment: ya i know that bro..but i have doubt..i have try this to bind attribute data like <code-input-text dirData="something"></code-input-text> instead of <code-input-text dir-data="something"></code-input-text>..but it not working.

Comment: @udays Please update your question with this code as well (+ the way `dir-data` is read), and explain *what* it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you created custom directive like

```
<codeInputText></codeInputText>
```

You have to use

```
<code-input-text></code-text-input>
```

it is better understanding of directive.

Comment: Because whole directive name itself indicator not part of directive.

Comment: if i use <codeInputText></codeInputText> like this, it will work or not?